# Add the page name to the body tag

Tags: php

I have the following PHP script that will add a class of .Active to the current open page - this bit works but I **am also trying to also add the page name to the body tag as an ID "#"**, but it does not seem to be working how I do it. Can anyone please advice me?

```
<!--add class .active to current page-->
<?php
   $directoryURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   $path = parse_url($directoryURL, PHP_URL_PATH);
   $components = explode('/', $path);
   $currentPage = preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "", end($components));

   if ($currentPage == "") {
      $currentPage = "index";
   }

   function href($url) {
      global $currentPage;
      $path = explode('/', $url);
      $page = preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "", end($path));
      echo 'href="' . $url . '" ';

      if ($page == $currentPage) {
         echo 'class="active"';
      }
   }
?>
```

Here is the menu:

```
<li><a <?php href('index.php'); ?>>Home</a></li>
<li><a <?php href('about.php'); ?>>About</a></li>
<li><a <?php href('treatments.php'); ?>>Treatments</a></li>
```

And the HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `echo 'class="active" id="$page"'`

Comment: I don't see a `<body>` tag anywhere in this piece of code. Define: `body`

Comment: body is the '<body>' of the page that comes after the '<head>' tag

Comment: Gee, thanks for the tutorial, as if I didn't know that.

Comment: Haha, Do you think a person with 8289 reputation doesn't know that. You code doesn't show the part where body tag is creating.

Comment: You're so right on both counts (lol) @Shanoop - Your comment (`+1`) in the answer below makes a lot of sense, not seeing what the OP has for code containing the `<body>` tag. Worthy of an answer, I'd say ;-)

Comment: Lol sorry, I thought you thought I meant something else.

Comment: Just updated my question, please review as the code now is fully there

Comment: Etiquette for functions to `return` and not `echo`, only for flexibility.

Comment: still you didn't give enough information. 
If possible show index.php too.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple add that variable **$page** in echo

```
echo "class='active' id='$page'";
```

Comment: That how I tried it first time, but it adds the id="page name" to the anchor it self, I want to apply it to the body tag

Comment: You gave only small part of your code. Just check were you are using body tag and there you can add echo, For ex <body class='<?php echo $curpage?>'> or echo "<body class='$curpage'>";

Comment: That did not work for me, as it need to be done from the function it self and not hard-coded in the Body tag.

Answer (score 0):

**Basically, if you don't want to modify the template, you can't.**

The solution would be to do this in your template, but it must be obvious to you:

```
<body <?php echo $id; ?>>
```

What seems less obvious to you, is just that you **can't** do this without touching the template.

Also, you should avoid global variables.